# Protected Mode Addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I am trying out boot loader development tutorials. I am able to read stage2 boot loader using FAT12 conventions. Now I am trying to load kernel in real mode and later copy it to 0x0100000 address.

I am getting triple fault while copying + jumping to 0x0100000.
Basically I am not able figure out how to access or jump to 0x0100000.

My code works when I use

```
IMAGE_PMODE_BASE equ 0x1000
IMAGE_RMODE_BASE equ 0x1000

krnl32.bin: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    i386-elf-ld -o $@ -Ttext 0x01000 $^ --oformat binary
```

What is it I am missing ? I read about descriptor: offset addressing in protected mode, it says DESC: OFFSET(16 bit).   Also offset is multiplied with 4KB using granularity setting in GDT.

I have set up gdt like this:

```
gdt_start: 
    dd 0                ; null descriptor
    dd 0 

; gdt code:             ; code descriptor
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10011010b        ; access
    db 11001111b        ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high

; gdt data:             ; data descriptor
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low (Same as code)10:56 AM 7/8/2007
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10010010b        ; access
    db 11001111b        ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high

end_of_gdt:
toc: 
    dw end_of_gdt - gdt_start - 1   ; limit (Size of GDT)
    dd gdt_start            ; base of GDT

; give the descriptor offsets names

NULL_DESC equ 0
CODE_DESC equ 0x8
DATA_DESC equ 0x10
```

I am linking kernel as below:

```
krnl32.bin: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    i386-elf-ld -o $@ -Ttext 0x0100000 $^ --oformat binary
```

Stage 2 boot loader

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x500]

jmp main

%include "boot/stage2/print16.s"
%include "boot/stage2/print32.s"
%include "boot/stage2/floppy16_driver.s"
%include "boot/stage2/fat12.s"
%include "boot/stage2/gdt.s"
%include "boot/stage2/a20.s"

;*******************************************************
;   Data Section
;*******************************************************

msgFailure db 0x0D, 0x0A, "Failed", 0x00
welcomeMessage db 0x0D, 0x0A, "Landed in STAGE TWO...", 0x00
enableA20Msg db 0x0D, 0x0A, "Enabled A20. Installed GDT", 0x00
ImageName     db "KRNL32  BIN"
ImageSize     db 0
IMAGE_PMODE_BASE equ 0xffff
IMAGE_RMODE_BASE equ 0x1000


main:
    ;-------------------------------;
    ;   Setup segments and stack    ;
    ;-------------------------------;

    cli                    ; clear interrupts
    xor     ax, ax             ; null segments
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     es, ax
    mov     ax, 0x0000         ; stack begins at 0x9000-0xffff
    mov     ss, ax
    mov     sp, 0xFFFF
    sti                    ; enable interrupts

    mov si, welcomeMessage
    call Print16

    call    _EnableA20
    call    InstallGDT
    sti
    mov si, enableA20Msg
    call Print16

    call    LoadRoot
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     ebp, IMAGE_RMODE_BASE
    mov     esi, ImageName
    call    LoadFile        ; load our file
    mov     dword [ImageSize], ecx
    cmp     ax, 0
    je      EnterStage3
    mov     si, msgFailure
    call    Print16
    mov     ah, 0
    int     0x16                    ; await keypress
    int     0x19                    ; warm boot computer

    jmp $;

EnterStage3:

    cli   
    mov eax, cr0
    or  eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp CODE_DESC:Stage3           


[bits 32]
Stage3:
    mov ax, DATA_DESC       ; set data segments to data selector (0x10)
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov esp, 90000h     ; stack begins from 90000h

CopyImage:
    mov eax, dword [ImageSize]
    movzx   ebx, word [bpbBytesPerSector]
    mul ebx
    mov ebx, 4
    div ebx
    cld
    mov    esi, IMAGE_RMODE_BASE
    mov edi, IMAGE_PMODE_BASE
    mov ecx, eax
    rep movsd                   ; copy image to its protected mode address
    jmp IMAGE_PMODE_BASE
    jmp $;
```

Comment: `div ebx` divides edx:eax by ebx. I don't see you zeroing out edx to avoid a divide overflow exception.

Comment: I recommend you run this in Bochs and debug it with its built in debugger. You'd be able to step through your code to see where and why it crashes. Bochs does a good job of debugging real mode code.

Comment: You can do division by 4 by shifting  register right 2 bits as well.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] so it is hard to help. You might consider making your project available on something like github. Possibly we'd be better able to help.

Comment: @Michael Petch :> That doesn't help. I think I am doing something wrong while using addresses. Either while copying image from Real Mode address to Protected Mode address or while jumping to protected mode address. How do you jump to 0x0100000 in protected mode?

Comment: @Michael Petch Could you please look at this.I am stuck here from while. https://github.com/zeoneo/i386-os/tree/master/part10-load-elf

Comment: If you are already in protected mode `jmp  0x0100000`

Comment: Thank you sir. It helped. My understanding of protected mode addressing was incorrect. I thought when we do jmp address ==>  jmp SEG_DESC:address.

Comment: You need to do `jmp SEG_DESC:address` to originally get into protected mode and set the protected mode CS selector that points to a 32-bit code descriptor in the GDT. Once in protected mode you can jump to any 32-bit address naturally. Only need to do `jmp SEG_DESC:address` if you need to make a change to the CS selector later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set up a GDT that has a 32-bit Descriptor for code and 32-bit descriptor for data. In protected mode the registers *CS/DS/ES/SS/FS/GS* are no longer segment registers in the sense they were seen in real mode. In protected mode they contain a selector that points to an entry in the GDT (or an LDT). This code loads the data registers:

```
mov ax, DATA_DESC       ; set data segments to data selector (0x10)
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov es, ax
```

You can't set the *CS* register like this. A *FAR* jmp can set both the code segment selector you want and sets the offset in one instruction. That is what this instruction does:

```
jmp CODE_DESC:Stage3
```

Your *GDT* is set up with code and data descriptors that are a 4gb flat memory model where the base is 0x00000000 and limit is 0xffffffff. This means once in protected mode and you are using selectors that point at these descriptors you can access all memory directly  from 0x00000000 to 0xffffffff. This means that all you need to do is `jmp 0x100000` to jump to memory address 0x100000. In your code you'll want to use 0x100000 as not only the place to jump to but also the memory location your memory copy uses as its base.

With that in mind, the simple fix is to change:

```
IMAGE_PMODE_BASE equ 0x1000
```

to:

```
IMAGE_PMODE_BASE equ 0x100000
```